# "make" command does not work in directories containing "space"

Tags: command-line, make, makefile

I often use `make` to compile programs. But, sometimes, only with some packages, when the directory contains a space, it says:

```
No such file or directory
```

Example:

If I run `make` in the directory `/home/akib/My Directory/`:

- If the directory exists, then:

  ```
  $ make
  make: *** /home/akib/My: Is a directory. Stop.
  ```
- If it doesn't exist, then:

  ```
  $ make
  Makefile:<line>: Directory/<file>: No such file or directory
  make: *** No rule to make target 'Directory/<file>'. Stop.
  ```

Is it a bug with `make` or the Makefile of the package? I think is it a bug with both `make` and the Makefile as this occurs only with some packages, and when this error occurs `make` tells about some buggy lines. I opened Makefile and saw that those lines contain variables. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It would probably be regarded as a "feature request" rather than a "bug" I think - see for example the discussion at [Can GNU make handle filenames with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it's a bug. More details here, it's documented as [#712](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?712)

You can alter the makefile by escaping spaces, i.e. `/home/akib/My\ Directory/`, but it's inconsistent and unpredictable at best, since it doesn't always work (best example I can come to mind is when expanding lists of names from variables).

Your best and quickest bet is renaming the problematic folder in the path with `_` instead of .

Is it a workaround? Yes. Is it working? Yes once more. Annoying? 3x Yes.

Comment: It is a feature!! Spaces if directory- and file-names has never been good prattice in Linux or Unix. Use "CamelBack notation" instead, "MyDirectory" instead of "My Directory".

Comment: True, and going by that principle avoid a lot of cumbersome escaping work. If you're writing portable code it's even more painful, so CamelCase or Under_Scores are the go-to practice.